How can I dramatically increase the logging from running pandas.DataFrame.to_csv with an S3 target?
There are many closed bugs claiming that pandas.DataFrame.to_csv fails silently when saving to S3 if it has problems on the S3 side. I think that I have another, but the number of sources claiming that these bugs are closed makes me uneasy. I want to submit a good bug report. How can I get as much logging as possible from running pandas.DataFrame.to_csv with an S3 target?
The errors parameter seems irrelevant. It is documented as only being for encoding/decoding issues. My issue is not regarding that. It is either to do with the S3 bucket being incorrectly specified or permissions being wrong. storage_options could be relevant, but I have yet to find how.

Are you using something like s3fs? my intuition tells me that perhaps you could look at it standalone and remove pandas from the equation. That might make debugging easier. Alternatively, maybe that will confirm it is a pandas issue.

@JonSG To my knowledge, pandas always uses s3fs.

I did not know that. I assumed you had to setup the s3fs file handler yourself and pass it to pandas. At least that is how I have always done it when working tith the non-pandas csv package.. TIL.

when you set the environmental variable S3FS_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG you should see debugging messages on stderr.

Have you tried the AWS SDK for Pandas (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-pandas)? It was previously called AWS Data Wrangler.
